# Equally spaced numbers with interval

Tags: normal-distribution

I've this very silly doubt in getting equally spaced numbers with fixed interval from a set of numbers.

Let's say I have a set of points, if I want maximum N points from this set equally distanced,

for ex:

- Total number of points in the set: 120
- Maximum number of points I want from it : 10

Then I can get like this,

1 * (120/ 10), 2 * (120 / 10)...... 10 * (120 / 10) ?

So that I will get 12, 24, 36... ,120 exactly 10 points with perfect interval.

I'm using a formula like, 1 * (X/N), 2 * (X/N), .... N * (X/N)

Is this right approach? Thanks for your time!

Comment: What do you mean by "uniformly"? Picking numbers with a uniform distribution (from a finite set) means that each number has the same probability to be chosen (possibly multiple times), not that the chosen numbers will be spaced equally.

Comment: I meant equally spaced. Sorry, will edit it.

Comment: Then you need a metric of sorts on your set. Also, you should specify if you wish that the intervals between any two points cover your set or not. Suppose for simplicity that your points are positive integers, and suppose that the distance between two numbers $x,y$ is $|x - y|$. Depending on how your set is defined it even is possible that the maximum size of a set of equally distanced points is $2$.

Comment: @BharathMg Is $x \in \{1, 2, 3, ..., 119, 120\}$ ? Then maybe this function will satisfy your conditions:

$$f(x)=\frac{\left\lceil \frac{x}{12} \right\rceil }{10}  $$

For example: $f(70)=0.6$

Comment: @A.P. I've a continuous integers, like {1,2,3,4..X} and I want  N number of integers from them, with equal interval (any interval number)...

Comment: If you wish to extract $N$ numbers, then the resulting number of intervals will necessarily be $N-1$. The point is: do you wish to always take the first and last number or not? If not, then you can always take any $N$ consecutive numbers in your set. If you do, then the problem may not have a solution: for example you cannot extract three equally distanced numbers from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, including $1$ and $6$, because there is no integer $a$ such that $a - 1 = 6 - a$.

Comment: By the way: your proposed solution for your example would work in the first case, as would $\{1,2,\dotsc,10\}$, but it wouldn't in the second case, because you are not taking $1$. The problem is that in the second case there is no solution: the only solution would be $\{ k \frac{119}{9} + 1\} : 0 \leq k \leq 9\}$, but at least some of those numbers are not integers, as $9$ doesn't divide $119$.

Comment: @A.P. Yeah your are right. I cannot get first and last numbers always. So, in my current implementation, I'm only taking 1 ≤ k ≤ N - 1 . And using my above formula (which is very same as you mentioned in your comment) to get the values. So, I guess what I'm doing is the only solution?

Comment: Your formula is similar, but not the same. Anyway, I cannot really tell you if that one is the only solution or not because (as I tried to explain in my previous comments) your problem statement is too vague.